# HTTPS Prerequiste for Button Click

Tags: angularjs, https, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular to make a user profile page that I only want to be accessible if connected using HTTPS.

```
<div>
        <p>Please access this page through SSL (https) to change your password.</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" ng-click="openPasswordModal()">Change Password</button>
</div>
```

What can I do to enforce that the button cannot be accessed except when the page is loaded in HTTPS?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you enforce this server side?

Comment: I believe there is some condition where some/most users are forced HTTPS but I as I understand the middle-ware currently does not enforce or check for HTTPS.

Comment: It might be easier to centralize the HTTP/HTTPS check on your AngularJS app `init` and force it there. Otherwise you'd scatter the HTTPS check across several places (or have to make it an AngularJS Service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, that's not how https works.. Pretty sure your web server needs to be configured to use SSL, it's not something the user has control over when visiting your site. If you're using IIS, see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324069. Otherwise try searching for "configuring https" for whatever web server you're using (IIS, Apache, etc.)

To answer your question about how to disable a button, you can use the ng-disabled directive. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled for more info.

Comment: I think the ng-disabled directve is what will work best for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce this in the client looking for https:// in the url field and redirect the user if he/she is using http://.

However the above is not recommended. You can always tamper with client-side scripts and disable such features.

Enforce this using apache/nginx or whatever webserver that you use.